# SBT: running end-to-end tests

Tags: sbt

I'm trying to setup sbt to run end-to-end tests.
What it needs to do:

1. Build and run the app: `sbt re-start` command
2. Execute integration tests against it `sbt e2e:test`

At the moment I can do both things separately, but not together with one command.

The end result should be `sbt e2eTests` which executes both tasks.

I added this to my `build.sbt`

```
val EndToEndTest = config("e2e") extend(Test)
val e2eSettings =
  inConfig(EndToEndTest)(Defaults.testSettings) ++
    Seq(
      fork in EndToEndTest := false,
      parallelExecution in EndToEndTest := false,
      scalaSource in EndToEndTest := baseDirectory.value / "src/e2e/scala")
```

plus

```
lazy val root =
  Project("root", file("."))
    .configs( EndToEndTest )
    .settings( inConfig(EndToEndTest)(Defaults.testSettings) : _*)
```

I created a dummy test in `src/e2e/scala` and I can run it just fine with `sbt e2e:test`

I know that tasks can depend on each other, but I have no idea how I can depend on `e2e:test` tasks. How do I reference it in my new `e2eTests` task?

Comment: `e2eTests := (e2eTests depensOn (test in EndToEndTest)).value` alike doesn't help?